# Static FBML tab - Dialog() stopped working

Tags: dialog, fbml, fbdialogs, staticfbml

Has anyone else experienced this?

```
var msgdialog = new Dialog();
msgdialog.showMessage('title', 'text');
```

It is completely ignored - no errors. Seems like this code is even stripped from the static FBML.

Answer (score 1):

As the FBML has been depreciated by Facebook. It is not reliable. As the FBML Docs read -
Please try not to rely on it.

"FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML. "

Comment: I know about the deprecation, but why would they remove Dialogs support all of a sudden? Just remove all endpoints right now instead of killing it slowly...

Comment: where is that 'Dialog()' class defined? is it in the old featureloader.js javascript SDK? That was removed a few months ago I think

Comment: I don't know where it is defined. When you try to use it in the Static FBML application, it simply doesn't work anymore.